# time- and space- complexity of a python function

Tags: time-complexity

Can anyone help me find out and explain what is the time- and space- complexity of the following python function?

```
 #L is a list of length N
 def countdist(L, i):
         if L[i] in L[i+1:]:
             return L[i+1:].index(L[i]) + 1
         else:
             return 2*N - i + 1
```

Comment: What is the type of elements populating `L`?

Comment: Please share some more details about what your ideas are, to give answerers a easier place to start.